# Software with which to develop a cloud platform

Tags: cross-platform, cloud-service, saas

I need to create a cloud platform which is supposed to expose services that other people will develop. The services are totally independent of one another and are supposed to be created using different technologies and still be able to work side by side, and be able to communicate with one another using grpc.

What software/tutorials/technologies are there for such a platform?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this is this too basic for you, but here we go:

I am currently taking part in a set of tutorials about the Google Cloud Platform (GCP), and so could you (of course there are other cloud vendors)

If you go to [Qwiklabs](https://google-run.qwiklabs.com/catalog) ( a company acquired by Google) you can do some hands-on labs and tutorials for free. However, for your question I'd recommend the non-free  "[GCP Essentials](https://google-run.qwiklabs.com/quests/23?catalog_rank=%7B%22rank%22%3A1%2C%22num_filters%22%3A1%2C%22has_search%22%3Afalse%7D)" series of short courses which can be completed in an afternoon. This would cost $8 (as of Jan. 2020). Then perhaps perhaps take more advanced tutorials, e.g. about Devops, and Kubernetes Engine on GCP .